# Is there a way to distinguish between subroutines of the same name in two different fortran90 modules?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

If I am unfortunate enough to have to work with two different Fortran90 modules that have a subroutine name in common, is there a way to distinguish between the two subroutines?

Comment: And BTW here there is quite big potential for a duplicate here, but I did not check yet. Things like using `private` and `only` should be obvious.

Comment: @VladimirF  I checked for a similar question before I posted.  Didn't find anything.

Comment: In that case see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `only`:

```
module m1
contains
  subroutine sub
  end subroutine

  subroutine other_m1
  end subroutine
end module

module m2
contains
  subroutine sub
  end subroutine

  subroutine other_m2
  end subroutine
end module

  use m1, only: sub, other_m1
  use m2, only: other2

  call sub
end
```

You can also rename one of them in the `use` statement:

```
  use m1
  use m2, some_other_name => sub

  call sub
end
```

Comment: The second sol'n is just what I need.  Have never seen that before.  Thanks.